# How to create a dict out of 2 dict's that already exist in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.5

How can I create a new dictionary out of 2 dictionaries that I already have created?
It should look like this:

```
d1 = {'a': 2, 'b': 3}
d2 = {'s': 4, 'k': 5}
```

The keys from d1 and the values from d2 have to be in d3.

```
d3= {'a': 4, 'b': 5}
```

Is there an operation that combines the keys from one dict and the values from another dict to create a new dictionary.

Comment: Dictionaries do not have ordering - this is not going to work.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking: How do associate which key from the first dict with which value of the second dict. What if they have different sizes? Your question is ill-defined. Is there a more specific problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: The dictionaries have the same size in this case and the fist key from dict1 should pair with the first value from dict 2 and so on.....

Comment: **Dictionaries do not have ordering**

Answer (score 3):

It can be done several ways. If you wish to use a loop you try this:

```
for i in range(len(d1.keys())):
d1[d1.keys()[i]]=d2.values()[i]
```

**Make sure the structure remains same of both the dictionaries.**

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries do not have ordering, then u can use OrderedDict or tuple and zip for union.

Example

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d1 = {'a': 2, 'b':3} 
d2 =  {'s': 4, 'k': 5} 
d1 = OrderedDict(d1)
d2 = OrderedDict(d2)
for value_d1,value_d2 in zip(d1.values(),d2.values()): 
    new_value = value_d1 + value_d2
```

Since you were not very specific in your problem, I have no way of trying to show something more elegant.

Answer (score -1):

```
d1={'a':2,'b':3}
d2={'s':4,'k':5}
k=list(d1.keys())
v=list(d2.values())
d3={}
for i in range(len(k)):
    d3[k[i]]=v[i]
```

Use check before the loop to make sure that number of keys equals number of values to avoid getting exceptions.